# ERROR: account.INVALID_ATTR_NAME (invalid attr name: invalid attr name) - zimbra

Tags: smtp, zimbra

I followed [this link](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Outgoing_SMTP_Authentication) to configure outgoing SMTP mail for Zimbra. In the step `zmprov ms <server> zimbraMtaSmtpSaslPasswordMaps lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/relay_password` zimbra show me the error's messege: `ERROR: account.INVALID_ATTR_NAME (invalid attr name: invalid attr name - unable to modify attributes: zimbraMtaSmtpSaslPasswordMaps: attribute type undefined)`. I googled this error but I got no result for this. So can someone tell me why, and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found why I got this error. Because the command I use is use for zimbra 8.5 (my zimbra version is 8.0) so it throw the error. In zimbra 8.0 use: `zmlocalconfig -e postfix_smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/opt/zimbra/conf/relay_password` instead of the above command.